# Getting a NaN when adding two values

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add 2 values together using jquery so that I can them output it to my total price. The error I get in my console is `NaN` and nothing else.
What I would like to happen is I get the value of `#totalPrice` and `#delivery-price` and add them together and output it in `#complete-price`. Though I do think that the error might be because of the `R` that is there. On the website it has to show `R100`

This is my code

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="4">
    <div class="float-right">
        Sub Total       
    </div>
  </th>
  <td id="totalPrice">R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>
</tr>

<tr class="delivery-fees">
  <th colspan="4">
    <div class="float-right">
        Delivery Fee
    </div>
  </th>
  <td id="delivery-price">R{{ $delivery }}</td>
</tr>

<tr class="total-price">
  <td colspan="4">
    <div class="float-right">
        Total:      
    </div>
  </td>
  <td id="complete-price">R{{ $total }}</td>
</tr>
```

This is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr("value")=="collection"){
            $(".delivery-fees").hide('slow');
        }

        if($(this).attr("value")=="delivery"){
            $(".delivery-fees").show('slow');

            var price = $("#totalPrice");
            var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price");
            var totalPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(deliveryprice);

            console.log(totalPrice);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to retrieve the `text()` from the `td` elements, then remove the `R` before performing any numerical operations on the values.

Comment: I would also suggest using `parseFloat()` on currencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have currency as well in td so you can not get that value. I will suggest you to add a data atrribute in html with price and use that for calculation.Change HTML as below:

```
<tr>
  <th colspan="4">
    <div class="float-right">
        Sub Total       
    </div>
  </th>
  <td id="totalPrice" data-price="{{ $totalPrice }}">R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>
</tr>

<tr class="delivery-fees">
  <th colspan="4">
    <div class="float-right">
        Delivery Fee
    </div>
  </th>
  <td id="delivery-price" data-price="{{ $delivery }}">R{{ $delivery }}</td>
</tr>
```

And now you can get these values in jQuery and use it as below:

```
    if($(this).attr("value")=="delivery"){
        $(".delivery-fees").show('slow');

        var price = $("#totalPrice").data('price'); //get data-price by this syntax
        var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").data('price');  //get data-price by this syntax
        var totalPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(deliveryprice);

        console.log(totalPrice);
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Please rewrite your code as below & have to remove `R` from the `<td id="totalPrice">R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>`

You can do it as:

```
<td>R<span id="totalPrice">{{ $totalPrice }}</span></td>
<td>R<span id="delivery-price">{{ $delivery }}</span></td>
```

`.text()` is missing

```
var price = $("#totalPrice").text();
var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").text();

var totalPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(deliveryprice);
console.log(totalPrice);
```

If you use `var price = $("#totalPrice");` its not a integer/string value, it will be like element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Sorry about that, i do not noted that is a table td id. Now, I have modified

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

1. `price` is a jQuery object, not an integer which can be parsed. In order to parse it you firstly need to get the text (ie the prices) from your two elements:

   ```
   var price = $("#totalPrice").text()
   var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").text();
   ```
2. Once you have retrieved the text (ie the price), you need to remove the prefix `R` from your strings:

   ```
   price = price.slice(1);
   deliveryprice = deliveryprice.split(1);
   ```
3. Although it may not be required, if your `price`/`deliveryprice` can be a float (have decimals), you should use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

Thus, you're altered code should look something like:

```
if($(this).attr("value")=="delivery"){
  $(".delivery-fees").show('slow');

  // get the prices as strings from your elements
  var price = $("#totalPrice").text();
  var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").text();

  // remove the "R" prefix so that can be casted to numbers
  price = price.split(1); // remove first character "R" from string
  deliveryprice = deliveryprice.split(1); // remove first character "R" from string

  // Calculate the total price
  var totalPrice = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(deliveryprice);

  console.log(totalPrice); // log the output
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to solve your problem you should add a span to your code like

```
 <td>R<span id="totalPrice">{{ $totalPrice }}</span></td>
```

so when you take the value you will get the value without the R string, then yo can do

```
var price = $("#totalPrice").html();
var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").html();
var totalPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(deliveryprice);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read the contents of any element with a separated closing tag with the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function. The split function removes the leading R.

```
var price = $("#totalPrice").html().split("R")[1];
var deliveryprice = $("#delivery-price").html().split("R")[1];
var totalPrice = parseInt(price) + parseInt(deliveryprice);
```